# Как упрощать логические выражения?

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, математика, логика

Пишу небольшой калькулятор логических выражений (булева алгебра)
Нужно запилить упрощение логического выражения (пример [здесь](http://tablica-istinnosti.ru/ru/)).

Есть синтаксическое дерево выражения (листья - операнды (константы и переменные), ветви - операции) Есть задача сделать упрощение выражений так, как это делает человек (с пояснениями каждого шага) (пример в прикреплённом скриншоте).
Сейчас есть только идея описать все правила замены (всякие законы де Моргана и тому подобные) и обходя дерево снизу перебирать эти правила
[image: Упрощение логических выражений]

Comment: Опишите более конкретно, в чем проблема и что у вас уже есть?

Answer (score 1):

Вижу, чего у вас нет: нет коммутативности, дистрибутивности и канонизации выражения. А вот идемпотентность найдена рановато - сначала просто коммутативность операции ИЛИ для четырёх операндов.
Ещё потребуются константы ИСТИНА и ЛОЖЬ и связанные с ними законы.
Для заоблачных выражений типа указанного можно посчитать таблицу истинности на 4 значения, построить по ней СДНФ и упростить (а лучше "узнать" таблицу по "шпаргалке").

Comment: Это ж не моё, это пример с [этого сайта](http://tablica-istinnosti.ru/ru/)

Comment: Ссылки - это хорошо, но в чистом виде здесь не приветствуются. Так что не увиливайте от ответственности.

Comment: Боюсь вы ответили не на заданный вопрос. Речь явно идет о минимизации методом применения законов и тождеств. Канонизация или построение таблицы истинности - это было бы слишком просто.

Comment: @tutankhamun цитирую ТС: "Есть задача сделать упрощение выражений так, как это делает человек (с пояснениями каждого шага)". Как человек, я бы использовал наиболее прямые пути к результату. Кроме того, применение закона идемпотентности в примере ТС требует перестановки логических "слагаемых" в определённом порядке (x, !x, y, !y). Под канонизацией в данном случае понималось именно это. Спасибо за то, что заставили меня уточнить эти  моменты.